# bash: background process not working without sleep command after that

Tags: bash

I have a bash script with lot of back ground process starting in it.

in the end i have the below background command

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xterm -T "PQXYMNLHARE" -hold  -e "sh /home/simha/.public_html/openmpv.sh \"000-${today}-${filename}\"" &
```

or

```
sh /home/simha/.public_html/openmpv.sh "000-${today}-${filename}" &
```

note: today and filename are defined in the script

It was not working at all. Surprisingly the same command i called many times in this same script and all of then open the xterm. But this end line does not open.

later after hours of struggle i just tried

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xterm -T "PQXYMNLHARE" -hold  -e "sh /home/simha/.public_html/openmpv.sh \"000-${today}-${filename}\"" &
sleep 10
```

Or

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xterm -T "PQXYMNLHARE" -hold  -e "sh /home/simha/.public_html/openmpv.sh \"000-${today}-${filename}\"" &
wgetpid5=$!
while true
do
    if kill -0 "$wgetpid5"
    then
        echo "working"
    else
        echo "closed"
        break;
    fi
done
```

Or

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xterm -T "PQXYMNLHARE" -hold  -e "sh /home/simha/.public_html/openmpv.sh \"000-${today}-${filename}\"" &
wgetpid5=$!
if kill -0 "$wgetpid5"
then
    sleep 1;
else
    echo "jalsdjlkj"
fi
```

Then the xterm opened and executed the script.

Where as:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xterm -T "PQXYMNLHARE" -hold  -e "sh /home/simha/.public_html/openmpv.sh \"000-${today}-${filename}\"" &
echo "textttt"
```

OR

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xterm -T "PQXYMNLHARE" -hold  -e "sh /home/simha/.public_html/openmpv.sh \"000-${today}-${filename}\"" &
wgetpid5=$!
if kill -0 "$wgetpid5"
then
    echo "worked" #Note replace sleep with echo
else
    echo "jalsdjlkj"
fi
```

Or Directly the command instead of xterm

```
sh /home/simha/.public_html/openmpv.sh "000-${today}-${filename}" &
```

None of the above didnt work

Whats the problem. I am clueless.

Only sleep or while loop after is making the command work.

Comment: I don't think this is reproducible, and it definitely seems unrelated to [tag:bash]. The only thing I can quickly think of is that the X server gets choked if you start too many programs too quickly. How many `xterm` instances were you starting and does starting one *without*  a `sleep` work in isolation after things settle down?

Comment: Does it have to be `sleep`? What if use put something else like `echo done` instead? Maybe it's just something special about the last command in the script.

Comment: Or perhaps it is the `1.mp4` instead of the `1.sh` ?

Comment: A [mcve] with steps someone else can follow to see the same problem would do a great deal of good. Right now, nobody can reproduce this who doesn't have your `/home/simha/1.sh` file (and, err, I *hope* you weren't trying to run a `.mp4` file as a shell script).

Comment: @Barmar: instead of sleep even i put a while loop and echo in it then also it works. As I mentioned I was also very confused why its not working. Its not the problem with the command. I run same command on the terminal it works.  And the same command is being run multiple times in the same code. Because the code is quite huge and not so organized i am not able to put it all.

Comment: please refer the updated question. I have added more cases

Comment: Are you running the script normally or with `source`?

Comment: what is source.